# Issues globally scaffolding vue in laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I have a laravel 8 project and in there I have a `main.blade.php` file that has `@sections` and `@yield()`s content. I have installed vue v2.x and am having issues placing the parent id of the root vue component. I keep getting this error on some pages in my app but not all.

```
[Vue warn]: Error compiling template:

tag <section> has no matching end tag.
  
<section class="content">
```

I can read so of course I check if the section tag it is complaining about has a matching closing tag. It does:

main.blade.php

```
 <div id="app">
     <section class="content">
         @yield('content')
     </section>  //matching closing section tag
 </div>
```

resources/app.js

```
import Vue from "vue";

window.Vue = require('vue');

Vue.component('spinner-button', require('./js/components/spinner-button.vue').default);

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
});
```

A lot of other files using my main.blade.php file via `@extends('templates.main')`

My component works fine on some pages but on other pages I get the browser error stated above. Where should I place the main app id?

Comment: If you remove the `<section>` tags just leaving `@yield` does the error persist? Do you have mismatched tags in one of the files that `yields`?

Comment: @Unflux i removed the section tags and same error. I went through one by one each file that uses the `@section('content')` and found zero typos or syntax errors. I am stumped.

Comment: Do a search in your vue/blade files for `<section class="content">`. One of them is has to be borked.

Comment: @Unflux I found it, it was an extra quote in a blade file. THanks